# rails params path with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently using some URL parameters to sort and categorize blog posts. For example, the parameter `category=politics` would pull all postings with the category of politics. Is there any way to load this with ajax or is a page refresh the best way?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your User Interface.

I tend to use Ajax a lot, it makes websites much more "smooth".

Well, your question is very close to this great Railscast, have a look! http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: You're welcome :) it's very important to keep an active community, users are the core of any language/framework. Btw, +1's are the way to show your gratitude ;)